# Calling C++ .dll libraries from MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, loadlibrary

Hopefully you all will be having good time. I am doing one project in which I have to call .DLL and .h files written C++ into MATLAB. Actually i have to interface one USB attachable device. The API of the device is written in C++ and have one .dll and one .h file. When I am trying to call these two from the MATLAB using loadlibrary in MATLAB, its working. BUt as this is only API so i wrote one .h and .cpp file to make the use of this API. now when I am loading .dll files written by my own, I am getting an error

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'USBCommAdapter.h': No such file or directory

where USBCommAdapter.h is original header file provided by the .dll files. It is available in the working folder of the MATLAB.

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The include file `'USBCommAdapter.h'` should be in the search path of Matlab. An easy way is to put it in current working directory. Input `path` command in Matlab to check if `USBCommAdapter.h` is in it.

Comment: Dear Sir..i did that..the solution was that i was including the header file with <USBCommAdapter.h> but when i did it like "USBCommAdapter.h"..it worked..any reason for this?...also in my C++ function i am giving arguments..now i want to give these arguments from matlab function means from calllib command...but it is giving error..i am doing like this calllib('libraryname','funcname',arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5)..can you please point me in right direction

Comment: with `<>` you search from system directory; and with `""` you search from current directory. The remaining question is another things. Post it as new question.

Comment: Dear Sir, thanks for the answer..i solved the above problems and posted another problem related to it..please see it and give some valuable suggestions. Thanks in advance
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566995/interfacing-device-visa-usb-in-matlab-using-c-dll-files