# Interfacing device visa USB in MATLAB using C DLL files

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, loadlibrary

I am doing a project in which i have to interface a device via USB using MATLAB. The API (dll files) of the device is written in the C++ so i used loadlibrary command in MATLAB to load it and done interfacing. It's working fine. The problem is that when i run the program from MATLAB it works fine but for running it again i need to plug out the device and then plug in to make it run successfully. But i wrote a C++ interface that is working fine. Can anyone tell me what should i do? The problem seems to be of getting the handle of the device but i am not getting the true point.

Comment: did you unload the library between the different runs:  [`unloadlibrary`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unloadlibrary.html)? Perhaps thats what you meant.

Comment: Dear Amro..thanks for your answer but i already solved this problem..the problem was that my devic has only interface communication channel and after getting the handle of that channel and doing my work..i was not shutting off the device means not closing that channel...and when other devices wants to get hold of that channel the error came..that's hwy i need to plug out and then plug in the device to get hold of channel. Thanks

Comment: you should post that as an answer and mark the question as solved (yes you can ask and answer your own questions!).